# Oracle command from date to date

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Here are my tables and I'm super lost:

```
      Command
noCommand date        numberClient
1         01/06/2000  10
3         02/06/2000  10


      Details
noLivre   noCommand
100       1
100       1
101       1
100       3
103       1


 Delivered
noLivre    Date
100        03/06/2000
101        04/06/2000
103        05/06/2000
```

What I want is all the noLivre from Details that touch at all the command made by client no 10 in june 2000

So I should get in return :

```
noLivre
100
```

And I'm super stuck any help ?

EDIT : I think Delivered table is just here to mess things up we probably don't need it.

What I have right now which doesn't work...

```
SELECT d.noLive
FROM Detail d
INNER JOIN Command c
ON c.noCommand = d.noCommand
WHERE c.date BETWEEN '01/06/2000' AND '30/06/2000' AND c.numberClient = 10
/
```

Results :

```
noLivre
100
100
103
101
100
```

Comment: Why is that result wrong? Your command table has entries for 1 and 3 for client 10; those commands appear in your details table for 100, 101 and 103, all in June 2000. Why are you only expecting to see 100?

Comment: because command 103 and 101 only at one no command but 100 touch at all the command and I want only the noLivre where noLivre touch at all the noCommand dont know if im clear english is not my first language

Comment: "that touch at all the command" is confusing; you meant "that have all of the commands", I think? So 100 should be included because it has both 1 and 3; the others are not included because they only have 1?

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the tables to get the results you want:

```
SELECT d.noLivre
  FROM DETAILS d
  INNER JOIN COMMAND c
    ON c.noCommand = d.noCommand
  WHERE c.Date BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JUN-2000 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                   AND TO_DATE('30-JUN-2000 23:59:59', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND
        c.numberClient = 10;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: If my date format is DD/MM/YYYY then i guess it should be :     WHERE c.dateCommande BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/JUN/2000', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                   AND TO_DATE('30/JUN/2000', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND
        c.noClient = 10

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of commands each `noLivre` has in the detail table, and compare that with the number of commands there are for the client in the command table.

```
select d.noLivre
from (
  select c.*, count(c.noCommand) over (partition by c.numberClient) as cntCommands
  from Command c
) c
join Detail d on d.noCommand = c.noCommand
where c.numberClient = 10
and c.dtCommand >= date '2000-06-01' and c.dtCommand < date '2000-07-01'
group by d.noLivre, c.cntCommands
having count(distinct d.noCommand) = c.cntCommands;

   NOLIVRE
----------
       100
```

I'm using an inline view with an analytic count of commands; with the data you showed that gets `cntCommands` as 2 for client 10. I've partitioned by `numberClient` in case you want to use the same method to find all clients that have all commands, for example; otherwise the `nuberClient` filter could be in the inline view too.

The inline view is then joined to the detail table, and number of distinct commands in that table is counted as well. Finally it's grouped and the `having` clause compares the total number of commands from the inline view (2) with the actual number of commands in the detail table. Only 100 has both 1 and 3, so its count is 2 - and matches - while 101 and 103 only have 1 - so do not match.